# Insert query returns one error for each unique key in Mondodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Let's say i have a username and email fields in my collection, and they are individually unique (not compound).

So when i execute a insertion query with an email and username that already exists in the collection i only receive an error about the email is duplicated.

what i want is, when a username is duplicated i receive an error about the username, a the same about the email. but when both are duplicated i receive an error saying that both are duplicated. how can i achieve that?

a simple illustration to the problem:

1st query:

```
collection.insert({email: 'jack@gmail.com', username: 'jack'})
```

2nd query:

```
collection.insert({email: 'jack@gmail.com', username: 'jack123'})
```

result: 'email is duplicated' wanted behavior

3nd query:

```
collection.insert({email: 'jack123@gmail.com', username: 'jack'})
```

result: 'username is duplicated' wanted behavior

4nd query:

```
collection.insert({email: 'jack@gmail.com', username: 'jack'})
```

result: 'email is duplicated' unwanted

wanted: 'email is duplicated, username is duplicated'

Comment: Are you using pure pymongo?

Comment: yes i am using a pure package

Comment: indexedDB is an in browser database for use in javascript, i removed the irrelevant tag `indexeddb`